# IOS Swift4 Not able to scroll a ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I hv been trying to make a scrollview scroll, just to the extent that the scrollview is supposed to show. However, I am not able to. This is my code.

```swift
func setupMainView() {
    // This is where the image view and other UIViews which are supposed to go in the contentview are set up
    self.setupImagesView()
    self.setupView1()
    self.setupView2()
    self.setupView3()
    self.setupView4()

    self.scrollView = UIScrollView()
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero;

    self.contentView = UIView()
    self.scrollView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.scrollView.layer.borderWidth = 0
    self.scrollView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

    self.contentView.addSubview(imagesScrollView)
    self.contentView.addSubview(view1)
    self.contentView.addSubview(view2)
    self.contentView.addSubview(view3)
    self.contentView.addSubview(view4)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
    self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero;

    var scrollViewHeight:CGFloat = 0.0;

    for _ in self.scrollView.subviews {
        scrollViewHeight += view.frame.size.height
    }
    var newHeight = scrollViewHeight * 1.1 + offset + 100
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:screenWidth, height:newHeight)
    scrollView.reloadInputViews()
}
```

The views are getting loaded etc, but I am not manage the scroll. It somehow either too little or too much.

Now, I tried setting the height of contentSize to `scrollViewHeight` and double of that etc. What I notice is that there is no predictability of how much it will scroll. Change from 1.1 to 1.6 .. there is too much whitescreen below the views, change it to 1.1 or 1.2 it does not even scroll to the bottom.

Note, everything has been set up programmatically, without storyboard etc.
Also note that I need to support all IOS devices with version > 10.

Am a little lost here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If i am not wrong then you are adding  scrollview twice in self.viiew `self.view.addSubview(scrollView)`. Please check

Comment: Good catch, but that does not seem to be the problem. Tried commenting out either line, but still not working.

Comment: Any particular reason you are not using AutoLayout?

Comment: I hv not used AutoLayout. Will give it a go, if this does not work. Why this does not work?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old way of configuring a scroll view - you should be using auto-layout.

And, you're doing a number of things wrong...

First, we'll assume you are setting frames of the various subviews in code you haven't shown.

However, the code you *have* shown creates a scrollView and adds it to `self.view` -- but you never set the frame of the scroll view.

Also, this part of your code:

```
for _ in self.scrollView.subviews {
    scrollViewHeight += view.frame.size.height
}
```

you've added several views as subviews of `contentView`, then added `contentView` as **the only subview** of `scrollView`.

***And...*** you are trying to increment `scrollViewHeight` by the height of your **root view** instead of the height of the scrollView's subviews.

So, `scrollViewHeight` will only be the height of `self.view`.

What you probably want to do is sum the heights of `contentView.subviews`:

```
    var contentViewHeight: CGFloat = 0
    
    for v in contentView.subviews {
        contentViewHeight += v.frame.height
    }
    contentView.frame.size.height = contentViewHeight
```

then set the scrollView's contentSize.height to the height of contentView's frame.

Here is a ***very, very basic*** example, using explicitly set frame sizes -- again, though, you should start using auto-layout:

```
class SimpleScrollViewController: UIViewController {

    var imagesScrollView: UIView!
    var view1: UIView!
    var view2: UIView!
    var view3: UIView!
    var view4: UIView!

    var contentView: UIView!
    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupMainView()
    }
    func setupMainView() {
        // This is where the image view and other UIViews which are supposed to go in the contentview are set up
        self.setupImagesView()
        self.setupView1()
        self.setupView2()
        self.setupView3()
        self.setupView4()
        
        self.scrollView = UIScrollView()
        
        // let's use a color other than white so we can see the frame of the scrollView
        self.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        
        self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero;
        
        self.contentView = UIView()
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        
        self.scrollView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.scrollView.layer.borderWidth = 0
        self.scrollView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        self.contentView.addSubview(imagesScrollView)
        self.contentView.addSubview(view1)
        self.contentView.addSubview(view2)
        self.contentView.addSubview(view3)
        self.contentView.addSubview(view4)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero;
        
        var contentViewHeight: CGFloat = 0
        
        for v in contentView.subviews {
            contentViewHeight += v.frame.height
        }
        contentView.frame.size.height = contentViewHeight
        
        // don't know what you're doing here....
        //scrollView.reloadInputViews()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        // here is where you know the frame of self.view
        //  so, make the scroll view cover the entire view
        scrollView.frame = view.frame
        
        // now, make contentView width equal to scrollView width
        contentView.frame.size.width = scrollView.frame.size.width
        
        // set the scrollView's content size
        scrollView.contentSize = contentView.frame.size
    }
    
    func setupImagesView() -> Void {
        imagesScrollView = UIView()
        imagesScrollView.backgroundColor = .red
        imagesScrollView.frame =  CGRect(0, 0, 300, 100)
    }
    func setupView1() -> Void {
        view1 = UIView()
        view1.backgroundColor = .green
        view1.frame = CGRect(20, imagesScrollView.frame.maxY, 300, 200)
    }
    func setupView2() -> Void {
        view2 = UIView()
        view2.backgroundColor = .blue
        view2.frame = CGRect(40, view1.frame.maxY, 300, 250)
    }
    func setupView3() -> Void {
        view3 = UIView()
        view3.backgroundColor = .yellow
        view3.frame = CGRect(60, view2.frame.maxY, 200, 275)
    }
    func setupView4() -> Void {
        view4 = UIView()
        view4.backgroundColor = .orange
        view4.frame = CGRect(80, view3.frame.maxY, 200, 100)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly you need to in order for scroll view to work you need to implement a couple of delegate methods. You also need a couple of properties set.

contentSize is one
and I think min and max size

see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate

also see Stanford University's
Paul Hagarty Developing IOS 11 apps with swift episode 9 for loads of information on UIScrollView

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B281mrPUGjg

seek to about 31mins for the scroll view information.

Answer (score 0):

This may help in the setup of `UIScrollView` programatically:

https://sheikhamais.medium.com/how-to-use-the-new-uiscrollview-programmatically-baf270ee9b4